# Save data on python script using a python script

Tags: python

Suppose I have the file `test.py`. I import it using the interactive interpreter, I add some strings to `data` in my file. How would I go about saving the file afterwards? Closing the interpreter keeps `test.py` in its original state. I've looked at a couple questions that told me to use `pickle`. However, one of the issues that was pointed out in the documentation was that `pickle` is not readable at all. I've tried using the `open` function, but I'm not sure how I would go about using it effectively.

Bottom line, how would I take data from a python script, add or remove parts of it, and then save it for use afterwards?

`test.py`:

```
# test.py
data = []
```

`Python Shell`:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.data.append("Hello There!")
>>> test.data
['Hello There!']
```

Comment: Don't keep the data in the script, keep it in a different file -- e.g. a .txt or .csv file -- and read and write it in the script. (Also, pickle files are readable -- perhaps you mean not *human* readable.)

Comment: The reason as to why I have it set up as a script is because I import it to read the data and perform functions on it. I assume it would be much more complex using a `.txt` file, since I would have to go through opening it, using the `.readlines()` method and slice everything up and all.

Comment: But to figure out where to write to in your python script you'd have to open it and use the readlines method and all.  Pickle is easy in the script, there are lots of automated csv readers if you don't want to use readlines, and anyway you should get competent enough to open and read a text file without thinking it's hard.

Comment: I think you should take a look at pickle again, here is a link https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to work with Python "data" files while saving them and preserving them as scripts.

While `pickle` lacks human readability, it's now become my choice in handling data and saving them. This is for the current program that I am writing, as well as future programs to come.

While pickle lacks *human* readability, at least it is *machine* readable, meaning that I won't have to go through loads of useless work. It's a compromise for the better.

Thanks to everyone that helped me come to like pickle.